# How can I center align my whole footer if it's divided into several floating divs that have centered text in them?

Tags: css, center

I have a footer made up of a few lists. I put each list in a div, and floating them so that the lists are horizontally next to each other. The text in each list is center aligned.
Now I'd like to center align all those divs! How can I do this? They are wrapped in a footer tag, but since the divs are floating, text-align:center; won't work.
Any ideas?
Thanks!

My CSS looks like this right now:

```
.footer{
height:180px;}

footer li{
list-style-type:none;
padding:0.2em 1em 0.2em 1em;
text-align:center;}

.section{
float:left;
margin-bottom:2.5em;
padding-top:0.8em;
margin-left:2em;}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To center an element, it'll typically need **margin: 0 auto** as stated in another answer.

If you want more elements *within* your container to center *within* the container, you should not be floating them. Floating them takes them out of the layout flow. You'll just want to make them display: inline-block.

```
* {
padding: 10px;
text-align: center;
}
footer {
background: #ddd;
}    
.item {
display: inline-block;
background: #999;
width: 20%;
}
```

Example:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RKQJNa

Answer (score 0):

```
.footer {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

This should align the footer in the centre

Comment: I tried that, but it won't work because the div sections are floating so that they are horizontal.. the footer is there, but technically doesn't have anything in it to align...!